# Node update from 12v to 16v issue - Accessing non-existent property 'splice' of module exports inside circular dependency

Tags: node.js, angular

We are getting debugging console error after updating the node version from 12 to 16. 'Promises' are not getting resolved after this error and further execution will also stopped.

```
 (node:28112) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'splice' of module exports inside circular dependency
    at emitCircularRequ**strong text**ireWarning (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:707:11)
    at Object.get (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:721:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\MyApp\apis\admin\component.js:1:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\MyApp\apis\admin\index.js:44:31)
apis/admin/component.js:1
(node:28112) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'splice' of module exports inside circular dependency
    at emitCircularRequireWarning (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:707:11)
    at Object.get (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:721:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\MyApp\apis\admin\component.js:2:31)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\MyApp\apis\admin\index.js:44:31)
```

App Versions
Angular CLI: 11.1.2 
Node: 16.15.1
npm: 8.12.2

Comment: Looks like `apis\admin\index.js` requires `apis\admin\component.js` which requires `apis\admin\index.js`. In other words, a [circular dependency](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#cycles).

Comment: I'm getting this same error while debugging a node express service inside VisualStudio Code. I'm not sure how to turn on the needed options (inside VSC) to get a full trace. My code seems to execute OK, but I'm nervous about the console complaint.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's a circular dependency as appointend by robertklep. I would recomend unninstall and run an "npm i" again, just in case.

Comment: I have tried the uninstall and install npm, but still its not working.